# Make a non-html5 input have a "placeholder"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple of `<input>` elements that I need to have HTML5-like placeholders for.  The kind that disappear on focus and reappear on blur only if the input has no text.  I've seen a few javascript-heavy implementations and I've been looking for a lightweight (preferably css-only) solution.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="email-container">
    <span class="default-value">Email</span>
    <input class="text-input" name="login" type="email"/>
</div>
<div class="pw-container">
    <span class="default-value">Password</span>
    <input class="text-input" name="login" type="pw"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Comment: For those interested, he wanted to answer his own question though. But, yeah I second that there are already enough polyfills out there for this (including SO itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that fit my bill perfectly (as in 'css-only'), but I did come up with a couple of good solutions using jQuery:

1. I set the background of the input to transparent and the z-index of the 'placeholder' text to -1.  This allows me to click 'on' the text and actually click the input. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AacP8/5/).
2. I allow the 'placeholder' text to sit over the input but I use a click handler on the text to transfer the focus to the input. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZR3k/2/).

In both instances, the workhorse of the implementation is this jQuery code:

```
$('.text-input').each(function(){
    var input = $(this);
    //Initially hide the default value if the input is non-empty
    input.siblings('.default-value').toggle(!input.val());
    input.on("focus blur", function(){
        if(input.val().length === 0){
            input.siblings('.default-value').toggle();
        }
    }
)});​
```

The other important piece to the puzzle was figuring out how to use `position: absolute` and `position: relative` to make the 'placeholder' text sit nicely inside the input while still allowing the input to move freely.

Comment: If you're interested in JavaScript solutions you may want to have a look at something like my [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) script, which may emulates the native `placeholder` behaviour more accurately. It will allow you to use the actual `placeholder` attribute, for a start.

Comment: The common method was to give the input a `data-default-value` (or some such other attribute, and switch its value between an empty string (when its value is the default) and visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

The Modernizer project has an excellent listing of cross browser HTML5 polyfills here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

If you go to that page and scroll down to "Web Forms : input placeholder", you'll see a number of excellent projects that will do exactly what you're looking for.